# How to fit all rows into datagridview so vertical scroll bar doesn't appear C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview object for Windows Form Application in C#. User can add some rows but this is limited to any number, so user can not enter too many rows.

I want to make all rows (row height and font size) autosized so they can fit into datagridview and vertical scroll bar does not appear. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Seiken, your answer really helped me to solve the problem! Some parts of it didn't work for me, so I changed them. I found a relation between font size and row height; I found three best font size for three different row height and made regression to find best font size for a specific row height.

```
 private void ResizeRows()
    {
        // Get the height of the header row of the DataGridView
        int headerHeight = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight;

        // Calculate the available space for the other rows
        int availableHeight = this.dataGridView1.Height - headerHeight;

        float rowSize = (float)availableHeight / (float)this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

        float fontSize = 0.8367F * rowSize - 3.878F;

        // Resize each row in the DataGridView
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Height = (int)rowSize;
            row.DefaultCellStyle.Font= new Font(dataGridView1.Font.FontFamily, fontSize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the available space for each row, then resize all of them:

```
private void ResizeRows()
{
    // Calculate the font size
    float fontSize = calculateFontSize();

    // Resize the font of the DataGridView
    this.dataGridView1.Font = new Font(this.dataGridView1.Font.FontFamily, fontSize);

    // Get the height of the header row of the DataGridView
    int headerHeight = this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Height;

    // Calculate the available space for the other rows
    int availableHeight = this.dataGridView1.Height - headerHeight - 2;

    float rowSize = (float)availableHeight / (float)this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count;

    // Resize each row in the DataGridView
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Height = (int)rowSize;
    }
}
```

You can add a call to this method in two of your DataGridView's events:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResizeRows();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_RowsRemoved(object sender, DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResizeRows();
    }
```

This way, your DataGridView should resize its rows each time a row is added or removed. You can experiment with different font sizes in the method `calculateFontSize`